# Font loaded multiple times in Chrome devtools

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, google-chrome-devtools, webfonts

I'm developing an Angular app, and I noticed that google fonts are loaded every time the page changes. It's not making a full page reload, it's an SPA, and I'm using angular routing.

To load the fonts, I copy/paste the link from google fonts page.

I saw this for example on firebase page too.

I'm using  Chrome Version 84.0.4147.89 (Official Build) (64-bit)

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Any ideas why this is happening and if this has any performance issued?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I don't know Angular but maybe this `link` element is inside the "routable" part of the page html.

Comment: @Diego did you ever figure out what was going on? I'm having the same issue, and have the same questions you do.

Comment: @mtoor No, I didn't. I have no idea why this is happening. The link element is in the head tag.

Comment: Same issue here in a React +Next JS app, and just in Chromium-based browsers (at least Chrome and Edge)

Comment: facing a similar issue in react app.  any solutions..

Comment: The problem might occur from adding third-party library. In my case the apexcharts library was making the fonts load a handful of times.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue now. And in my case the reason was using special characters (HTML codes) in some templates.

HTML symbol codes, such as & for "&" or < for "<", are entities that represent special characters. When a browser encounters these symbol codes in the HTML source code, it needs to render them as the corresponding characters. To do this, the browser may need to rely on a specific font that includes the necessary glyphs for those characters.

Now, if the font referenced in your CSS or HTML does not have the required glyphs for the symbols used in your template, the browser will attempt to load a fallback font that does have those glyphs. This fallback font might be a different font altogether, or it could be a variant of the same font that includes additional glyphs.

In some cases, the fallback font loading behavior can cause the font to be loaded multiple times. For example, if the primary font specified in your CSS does not have the necessary glyphs for the symbols, the browser may load a fallback font to render those symbols correctly. However, if the fallback font also does not contain the required glyphs, the browser may need to load another fallback font or retry the font loading process. This can result in multiple font loads and impact performance.

So for these places I just provided `font-family: 'sans-serif'` and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 font weights of Roboto, and for each weight, it will generate a separate request. I can see the font file repeated three times.

Do you have any other third-party services running on your website (or app), and if they use Google Fonts, that will also appear in the requests. If they use the same Roboto font, it will contribute to the request count.

You can click on the initiator column in the font tab, and it will take you to the source file.